# Access Meteor Collections from MongoDB Issue?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have created & deploy one app using `Meteor`. The deploy name **myapp.meteor.com**. I have connected to `Mongo DB` using the below procedure:

Command Prompt From Meteor :

```
Meteor mongo myapp.meteor.com

//Below one is Response from  Meteor mongo myapp.meteor.com command

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: production-db-b3.meteor.io:27017/myapp_meteor_com
```

Command Prompt From MongoDB:

```
use myapp_meteor_com
```

I have created **Emp** collection using myapp code.From Mongo DB command prompt i will try to see collections to created from myapp But it doesn't show.And i am using to show collections using below procedure:

```
connecting to: test
> show dbs
myapp_meteor_com      (empty)
local   0.078125GB
> use myapp_meteor_com
switched to db myapp_meteor_com
> show collections //here shows nothing but js file contains `Emp Collection` and data inserted as shown below.
>                     //here no collections shows.
```

So i didn't have any idea show please suggest me what to do for above problem?

//Here data inserted to Emp collection obj.
JS Code :

```
if (Meteor.isServer) 
{
    Meteor.startup(function () 
  {;

           if (Emp.find().count() === 0) 
           {
               for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
               Emp.insert({ fname: "xxx",userid: i, email : "abc@gmail.com"});

            }
  });


}
```

Comment: sometimes collections are actually created when you write something to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have created collections using `Emp = new Meteor.Collection("emp")` (if you did this).

The thing is that the collections will only be created if you insert data into them. If you create a collection in the way like above, you've only declared it as a variable and the collection will not appear in mongodb.

This is generally how mongodb works: The collections are created automatically when you insert data into them.

Comment: Yeah,But the Created Collections how to see from Mongo DB command prompt?.@Akshat.

Comment: The same way you are doing, you haven't done anything wrong there. You've just not inserted any records so you wont have any collections.

Comment: Yeah,But it doesn't shows the collection names.@Akshat

Comment: Is the information you have provided exactly as you are doing? In your previous questions often your questions don't match what you have

Comment: Apologies i cant think of anything else it could be apart from some information you may have missed or you may have not inserted any data.

Comment: No,Data is there but it doesn't shows.even predefined collections also not shows.I didn't get what mistake i did.So please help me?.@Akshat.

Comment: Can you please see the above posted code once because i has changed to somecode?.@Akshat